# Dual Monitor Tearing, Missing Compiz Refresh Rate,

Tags: nvidia, compiz, multiple-monitors, 13.10, tearing

I've poured over dozens of forums looking for an answer to this, but I'm stumped.

I'm using dual monitors of different resolutions and have screen tearing (rather minor, but noticeable), likely caused by the different refresh rates. One screen defaults to 60hz, the other to 75. I am able to change the refresh rates in the nvidia-settings and change them both from "auto" to 60hz (both monitors support this rate), however, upon restart they have reset back to their default setting of "auto"(auto being one at 60hz and the other at 75hz).

Previously, I had used a startup script that made ccsm force a 60hz rate(compiz also would reset to default upon restart) and this had fixed the issue.

However, upon upgrading to 13.10 the refresh rate in CCSM is blank for me and shows nothing. If I enter anything into it, it will reset itself back to black upon hitting the back button.

So, essentially, at the moment, I cannot enter anything into ccsm for a refresh rate, and any settings I set in nvidia-settings don't stick at startup.

Xrandr does show that the 60hz is available for the second monitor, but I am unable to find a way to ensure that it starts with that rate.

And, unless I'm reading it incorrectly, my xorg.conf does show a 60hz rate:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.17  (buildd@rhenium)  Sun Oct 27 00:28:28 UTC   2013


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "Mouse Remap"
    MatchDevicePath    "/dev/input/event*"
    Option         "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AOC LM720BGE"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 560 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: 1280x1024_60 +1920+56, DVI-I-2:  1920x1080_60 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Anyhow, any advice or suggestions anybody has would be greatly appreciated. Again, I can change the refresh rate manually and everything works fine, it just doesn't stick past a restart.

Also, I'm not sure if it's normal, but it only shows my smaller crappier monitor in the xorg.conf and not the larger one, though, both are in use.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, nvidia 331.17, let me know if you need any more information.
Cheers,

Tara

Answer (score 0):

It's dirty fix, but works for me in Ubuntu 13.10.

---

In section "Monitor" i changed **VertRefresh     75.0 - 75.0** and added to section "Screen:" **Option         "UseEDIDFreqs" "False"**

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05)  Wed Oct 30 18:20:32 PDT 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ FP93GX+"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     75.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 260"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1280x1024_75+0+0"
    Option         "UseEDIDFreqs" "False"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```